# show that $f(x,y) =2x^2 + 3y$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ by producing a linear function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives, proof-verification

Here's the question: 
Prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 3y$ is differentiable at $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ by producing a linear function T and show that the appropriate limit is 0.

Here's what I got:

$$ Df(0,0) = \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Vert f(x+h, y+h) - f(x,y) -Th \Vert}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(h,h) - f(0,0) -Th ||}{||h||} = \frac{|| 2h^2 + 3h -Th ||}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|| h(2h + 3 - T) ||}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 2h + 3 - T = 0$$

And for the last equality to hold, we need $T=3$.

Thoughts? I'm not very confident in my answer, although nothing is jumping out to me as wrong.

Comment: $T$ should be a linear map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You need to have something like $f(x+k,y+h)-f(x,y)-T(k,h)$.

Comment: @Craig I see you're a new user. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @Craig Do you still need help with this?

Comment: So if I do it with T(k,h), then I get a number of possible answers. How do I confirm which is correct? For example, I could do $T(k,h) = 2h + 3$ and that would make the limit zero, or I could do anything else that includes a $+3$ with the rest of the terms h such that they go to zero